# How to make my search bar in react native working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am learning react native by myself. I try to create a research bar but nothing seems to work. 
I know how to get one element from my data list, but I don't understand why it is not working and how to make it work properly. 
To be more specific I have a list of farmer and I want to filter them based on the city they work.

My code is :

```
import React from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import data from '../Helpers/FarmersData.js'
import FarmerItem from './FarmerItem'
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

// return data.filter(function (e){return e.City == text}).map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> );

class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          farmers: [],
          searchedText: "" 
        }
    }

    _searchTextInputChanged(text) {
        this.setState({ searchedText: text })
    }

    _loadFarmer() {


        if (this.state.searchedText.length > 0) { // Seulement si le texte recherché n'est pas vide
            data.filter(e => e.City == this.state.searchedText).map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> ).then(data => {
              this.setState({ element: data.results })
          })          
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Nom du maraicher'/>
                <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => {this._loadFarmer()}}/>
                {data.map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> )} 

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I followed lot of tutorial, but nothing seems to work. I am completely despair. 
It is certainly something easy but for a non-developer like me, it's kinda difficult. 
I hope someone can help! 
Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: Do you have any expo project?

Comment: Yes, I have one

Comment: Can you update your post with expo link?

Comment: I am sorry to ask that but...  How can I do that ?

Comment: just paste your code in the expo snack and it hsould be working

Comment: You can just use React's Native element search bar -->https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html

Comment: Done! And I already try but I didn't make it work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : in constructor we are set our all farmers to farmers

Step 2 : TextInput has onChangeText so we can use our text directly like you show in

Step 3 : in _searchTextInputChanged we can access our text so we are filtering our text with our farmers data.

You can see if we have farmers with city then we are assign it to our state else we are set our all data to state as you can see in _searchTextInputChanged

```
import React from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet , Text } from 'react-native'
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import data from '../Helpers/FarmersData.js'
import FarmerItem from './FarmerItem'
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

// return data.filter(function (e){return e.City == text}).map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> );

class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          farmers: data ,
          searchedText: "" // Initialisation de notre donnée searchedText dans le state
        }
    }

    _searchTextInputChanged = async (text) => {
        const newData = await data.filter(e => e.City.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase() );

        //change your logic as per your requirement 
        if( newData.length > 0 ){
        this.setState({farmers : newData})
        }else{
        this.setState({farmers : data })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <>
            <View style={styles.main}>
                <TextInput style={styles.textinput} onChangeText = {(text) => this._searchTextInputChanged(text)} placeholder='Nom du maraicher'/>
                {this.state.farmers.map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> )}

            </View>
            </>
        );
    }
}

// Components/Search.js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex:1,
        marginTop:30,
        backgroundColor:'white'
    },
    textinput: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        height: 50,
        borderColor: '#86d972',
        borderWidth: 1,
        paddingLeft: 5
    }
  })

export default Search
```

Comment: and let me know what you are getting in your    console.log('newData',newData);

Comment: Where is console.log... ?

Comment: replace your _loadFarmer with my ans and run you app

Comment: I get a syntax error : SyntaxError: D:\MaRegionBio\Components\Search.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (24:27)

  22 |     }
  23 | 
> 24 |     _loadFarmer = async () {
     |                            ^
  25 |         if (this.state.searchedText.length > 0) {
  26 |           const newData = await data.filter(e => e.City == this.state.searchedText);
  27 |

Comment: _loadFarmer = async () => {

Comment: I have no log and my app is constantly charging while I not getting the ' something went wrong' error

Comment: I tried your update and it's working! I am so happy ! Now, I have to understand what you did!

Comment: i have updated my answer.let me know if you steel have any query

Comment: I have one ! What is async function and what 'await' do ? 'Await' will make waiting for the data comparaison done ?

Answer (score 0):

Thisd is a working solution :

[snack-expo](https://snack.expo.io/H1gTESVbI) Do check once with abc as input , for more doubts i can clarify:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet,Text } from 'react-native'
import { ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
// import data from '../Helpers/FarmersData.js'
// import FarmerItem from './FarmerItem'
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

// return data.filter(function (e){return e.City == text}).map(element => <FarmerItem farmer={element} key={element.id} /> );

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          farmers: [],
          searchedText: "" ,
          data:[{
            name:'a',
            city:'ABC'
          },{
            name:'b',
            city:'WOW'
          }
          ],
          dataShown:[{
            name:'a',
            city:'ABC'
          },{
            name:'b',
            city:'WOW'
          }]
        }
    }

    _searchTextInputChanged = (text) => {

        let newDataF = [];
        this.state.data.map((e) => {
          if(e.city.toLowerCase() == text.toLowerCase())
          {
            newDataF.push(e)
          }
        })


        this.setState({ searchedText: text, dataShown:newDataF })
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{marginTop:100}} >
                <TextInput onChangeText={this._searchTextInputChanged} placeholder='Nom du maraicher'/>
                <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => {this._loadFarmer()}}/>
                {this.state.dataShown.map(element => <Text>{element.city}</Text> )} 

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! It's not working.. I try it on snack-expo and on my device

Comment: i mean have you searched abc? its working for abc . coz data is my dummy data, you can make your won data

Comment: I have a file with my data that is exported with this : ```import data from '../Helpers/FarmersData.js'```. Is it not the same as you data table ?

Comment: i dont have data right, so i made my own dummy data just to show you how it works. implemnt the same way in your app

Comment: Ok...  but then, how to get data from another file ? maybe that is my problem ?

Comment: import the variable that you are exporting from there.